# Good way to get size of class for binary serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm writing some classes that are going to be used to communicate with a C# TCP server, and I'm writing serialization/deserialization methods using `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`. This is easy enough, but I've run into a situation where I have a class Class1 that contains an instance Class2 inside. Both classes implement an interface that defines methods `byte[] ToBytes()` and `void FromBytes(byte[] data)`. So I've got this code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Action;
    public Class2 Data;

    public void FromBytes(byte[] data)
    {
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));
        Action= br.ReadInt32();
        Data = new Class2();
        Data.FromBytes(br.ReadBytes(___));
        br.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is, what goes into the `ReadBytes` call? I'm not sure of a way to do it other than to hard-code the size of any object that implements this interface, but is there something more elegant? I considered using reflection to calculate it at run-time (caching it for future calls), but this seems even uglier.

edit: I should point out that if the data is going to be variable-length, the binary representation includes the data lengths where necessary, and the deserializer would handle it.

Comment: Serialization does not typically produce a fixed-length representation.  You might do better with a constrained stream, or any other approach that accepts that the receiving end won't know the length until it's finished reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, rather than passing a `byte[]`, I would pass the `Stream` (perhaps a constrained-stream, to stop it from reading outside of our expected region) or the wrapping reader, and use that - i.e. let the class read what it needs.

Another simple option is to length-prefix the data during serialization, so that you know the size is in advance.

Or, save a lot of bother and use a pre-rolled binary serialization framework. There are several... they have all had to solve this problem. Happy to advise (it is a pet area of mine).

I also worry about separation of concerns in your class, but that is a side-issue.

Comment: I'm familiar with protobuf-net, but that would be a bigger commitment than I want at the moment (maybe, hopefully down the line). are there any pure .net solutions you're familiar with and would recommend?

Comment: By "pure .net" do you mean "in the MS BCL"? probably not for your scenario. protobuf-net is pure .net, though. And note I didn't even mention it! I had to bite my tongue hard, though.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps put the size of the instance at the beginning of the instance's data? Although, if you're using a `BinaryReader`, you should be able to just pass the reader itself to a method in the `Class2` object and it can use it to deserialize the binary data.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, and without going into the merits of how correct your approach to this problem is, **`Marshal.SizeOf`** should solve your problem.

I took the liberty of filling the blanks in your code:

---

```
class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class Class2
    {
        public int Data;
        public int SomeMoreData;

        internal void FromBytes(byte[] p)
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(p));
            Data = br.ReadInt32();
            SomeMoreData = br.ReadInt32();
            br.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public int Action;
        public Class2 Data;

        public void FromBytes(byte[] data)
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));
            Action = br.ReadInt32();
            Data = new Class2();
            int sizeOfClass2Instance = Marshal.SizeOf(Data);
            Data.FromBytes(br.ReadBytes(sizeOfClass2Instance));
            br.Close();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();

        int[] data = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
        byte[] dataInBytes = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(int)];

        for (int i=0;i<data.Length;i++)
        {
            byte[] src = BitConverter.GetBytes(data[i]);
            Array.Copy(src, 0, dataInBytes, i * sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
        }
        c1.FromBytes(dataInBytes);
    }
}
```

---

The trick is, Marshal.SizeOf relies on the StructLayout attribute on your class. You must be explicit on how data is stored in your class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that every object of Class2 delivers the same amount of bytes when using ToBytes, create a dummy object of Class2 and use ToBytes().Length.

Or just:

```
    Data = new Class2();
    Data.FromBytes(br.ReadBytes(Data.ToBytes().Length));
```

(obviously you can make this more efficient by storing Data.ToBytes().Length somewhere and reuse it).

Comment: Let's hope there are never any strings (or other data of unpredictable length) in the data ;-p

Comment: there actually aren't, it's all numeric, but a fair warning. maybe I should just go with protocol buffers like everyone else ;)